# How to get HTML code on browser from URL

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to get html code on preview mode in browser

[like this link](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/coma/1a77d6632edf5426fcd8/raw/73bf3c9549256710bb1c23bbc27bf10c8aa694ac/colors.html)

Actually this link's output should be "**{{ color.name }}**"

Answer (score 0):

Right click the page from the browser and select 'view page source'

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the page and take view page source
2. put view-source: infront of your url

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any special script there, just

```
<pre>
...
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Within web browsers right click on the page and select "page source"
  or "view page source".
- Or press shortcut CTRL + U.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome and or Firefox you right click and select 'view page source'. You can even go to the menu and select developer tools and see the whole nine yards from html/css/js.